# After configuring Spring Web security login gives me Invalid username and password error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

After configuring Spring's Web Security my register works expected but when I try to login my login page says that my username or password is invalid a I am using in memory h2 database and I checked database values after register if I am typing in correct (username, password). When i used hardcoded values in UserDetail Service login worked like expected

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/h2-console/**", "/register", "/users")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
        //ovo popravlja problem whitelabel error kod pritiska na gumb
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Sql DataBase:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authorities;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;



create table users (
                       id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                       username varchar(50) not null ,
                       email varchar(120),
                       password varchar(255) not null,
                       enabled boolean
);

create table authorities (
                             username varchar(50) not null,
                             authority varchar(50) not null,
                             foreign key (username) references users (username)
);
```

Spring boot log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-04-12 14:12:04.739  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.m2.cfg.TestApplication               : Starting TestApplication using Java 15 on DESKTOP-EFU4KH0 with PID 17532 (C:\Users\Tome\Downloads\spring-security-jpa-master\mc2-test\target\classes started by Tome in C:\Users\Tome\Downloads\spring-security-jpa-master\mc2-test)
2021-04-12 14:12:04.745  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.m2.cfg.TestApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-12 14:12:05.893  INFO 17532 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-12 14:12:05.961  INFO 17532 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 56 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-12 14:12:06.578  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-12 14:12:06.588  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-12 14:12:06.588  INFO 17532 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-12 14:12:06.751  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-12 14:12:06.751  INFO 17532 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1908 ms
2021-04-12 14:12:06.804  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-12 14:12:06.922  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-12 14:12:06.929  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2021-04-12 14:12:07.111  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-12 14:12:07.159  INFO 17532 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-12 14:12:07.278  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-12 14:12:07.399  INFO 17532 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-04-12 14:12:07.550  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator   : HHH000398: Explicit segment value for id generator [hibernate_sequences.sequence_name] suggested; using default [default]
2021-04-12 14:12:07.958  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-12 14:12:07.971  INFO 17532 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-12 14:12:08.113  WARN 17532 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-12 14:12:08.573  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@43df1377, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7f64bd7, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5badeda0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2ba318c2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@67c2b55d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@746fd19b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7a587e84, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1cee3e05, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1dd247b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@40b01718, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@565a6af]
2021-04-12 14:12:08.749  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-12 14:12:09.040  INFO 17532 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-12 14:12:09.057  INFO 17532 --- [           main] com.m2.cfg.TestApplication               : Started TestApplication in 5.008 seconds (JVM running for 6.678)
2021-04-12 14:12:13.285  INFO 17532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-12 14:12:13.285  INFO 17532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-12 14:12:13.286  INFO 17532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-04-12 14:12:13.490  WARN 17532 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [145] milliseconds.
```

**h2 database values**

[image: h2]

Register Controller class that contains PasswordEncoder @Bean and writes objects to h2 in memory database:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String read(@ModelAttribute(name = "user") Users user, Model model) {

        if(user.getUsername() != null && user.getEmail() != null && user.getPass() != null)
        {
            var u1 = new Users(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPass()));
            userRepository.save(u1);
        }
        return "register";
    }
}
```

and Login html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
<br>
<a href="register.html">register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

User repository:

```
package com.m2.cfg.repository;

import com.m2.cfg.domain.Users;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Users findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `PasswordEncoder` bean in a file that you have not shared? You password in the database looks to be encoded using BCrypt, which means your application needs to know to compare the passwords using BCrypt.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana how can I do that? "Say to app that it needs to compare with BCrypt" ... but on other hand i tried using hardcoded users with Insert into query so passwords would be written to db directly with no encrypt and then i would get message in log that password doesnt look like its using BCrypt and i would get wrong username/pass error on page

Comment: It seems like there is nothing telling Spring Security to use the `UserRepository`. Rather than accessing the repository directly, try exposing a `UserDetailsManager` Bean. It would simply return `return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);`. Then in your Controller autowire the `UserDetailsManager` instead of the repository and call `userDetailsManager.createUser(u1)` to save the user.

Comment: But user is saved in database as expected its just problem with validation while trying to login

Comment: I'm concerned that Spring Security doesn't know that it should retrieve the users from that specific database table. Creating a `UserDetailsManager` that accesses the database table will let Spring Security know.

Comment: can you please post your spring security debug logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `WebSecurityConfig`. there is no `PasswordEncoder` configured.
Since the entered password is compared in unencoded state, invalid message is shown.

Move the `PasswordEncoder` bean to `WebSecurityConfig` and configure `PasswordEncoder` as follows.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(encoder());
}
```

Comment: That's not problem cuz i tried with hardcoded values and inserted values to password field directly with no crypting and it still didnt work...

Comment: @TomeVersic  
To use `jdbcAuthentication`, there must be `enable` column in  `users` table.
But when I look at your h2 database image, there is no `enable` column.
Please check it. If this is not the case, I would also like to upload the error log.

Comment: there is enabled column in users table look better

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

to the `WebSecurityConfig` class.

Comment: would it matter? Isn't it that anything annotated with @Bean would first be registered and picked up where ever required irrespective of the file?

Comment: IMHO it only works in @Configuration classes

Comment: Its not problem in that ... I too thought that problem was in comparing of hashed password and plane password but i removed all encryption for testing purposes and its still not working